# Docker - Force to Use AUFS Instead of BTRFS

Tags: btrfs, docker, aufs

I am having significant problems using Docker on my BTRFS filesystem, and I suspect that is due to a lack of stability with the BTRFS driver. I would rather figure out how to switch the fs driver than ask multiple questions about the problems I have been having. Originally it would fill my hard drive with about 4 builds of any Dockerfile and deleting images and containers would not help (and this is with ~80GB of space left); I also had to delete BTRFS subvolumes from `/var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes`. Now I have a still-more-annoying problem where no images can be pulled because a file or directory exists (in a location which is completely removed first). So because these problems have been so cryptic and un-Googleable, I'd like to just force the driver to be AUFS. How do I go about doing this? I am using 64-bit Arch Linux. Any guidance or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the AUFS driver doesn't work well over BTRFS file systems. My best experience with docker on BTRFS was using docker's BTRFS storage driver (`-s btrfs` in docker's options).